# Can't update props of child components generated from JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux, reactjs-flux

I just started learing react and I run in a trouble trying to update state of a single `<Option />` child Element.

My flux Store is emiting change and in React devtools I can see the state of StyleOptions element being updated but it doesn't update the child components `<Option />`.

I suspect this is because I got the list of options kept in a variable.

I need to use this because I'm pulling this options from JSON.

```
const Options = this.state.options.map((parent) => {
        const children = parent.children.map((child) => {
          return (
            <Option {...child} />
          )
        });
        return <Option {...parent} children={children} />;
    });
```

So I think this part might be causing problems.

My example data from `OptionsStore` looks like this.

```
this.options = [
      {
        key: "suitType",
        label: "Suit Type",
        selected: false,
        children: [
          {
            key: "suittype_skinny",
            parent: "suitType",
            label: "Skinny",
            price: "£50",
            description: "Short description",
            images: {
              general: "http://placehold.it/600x600",
              closeUp: "http://placehold.it/620x620",
              thumbnail: "http://placehold.it/100x100",
            },
            selected: false,
          },
          {
            key: "suittype_wedding",
            parent: "suitType",
            label: "Wedding",
            price: "£50",
            description: "Short description",
            images: {
              general: "http://placehold.it/600x600",
              closeUp: "http://placehold.it/620x620",
              thumbnail: "http://placehold.it/100x100",
            },
            selected: false,
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Also the child props aren't being changed.

Full code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Option from './Option';
import OptionsStore from '../../stores/OptionsStore';

class StyleOptions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      options: OptionsStore.getAllItems(),
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    OptionsStore.on('change',(e) => {
      this.setState({
        options: OptionsStore.getAllItems(),
      });
      console.log('optionsStore received an update');
    });
  }
  render() {
    const Options = this.state.options.map((parent) => {
        const children = parent.children.map((child) => {
          return (
            <Option {...child} />
          )
        });
        return <Option {...parent} children={children} />;
    });
    return(
      <div className="col-xs-6">
        <ul className="list-group">
          {Options}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StyleOptions;
```

also the `<Option />` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.hasChildren = this.props.children ? true : false;
      this.hasThumb = this.props.images ? true : false;
      this.children = this.state.children;

    this.state = {
      label: this.props.label,
      description: this.props.description,
      selected: false,
      price: this.props.price
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li className={this.hasChildren ? 'list-group-item':'col-sm-4 list-group-item' } selected={this.state.selected}>
          <a className="media">
            {this.hasThumb ? (
            <div className="media-left media-middle">
              <img src={this.props.images.thumbnail} alt={this.state.label} />
            </div>
            ) : (
              ' '
            )}
            <div className="media-body">
              <h4 className="option-name">{this.state.label}</h4>
              <p className="info">{this.state.description}</p>
              <span className="text-success pricing">{this.state.price}</span>
            </div>
          </a>
          {this.hasChildren ? (
              <ul className="panel-body">
                  {this.children}
              </ul>
            ) : (
              ' '
            )}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is inside of your Option component.
You define `this.children = this.state.children` . After that, you define your initial state but there is no "children". So that children state is notdefined.

First, add `children: this.props.children` into your state.

Then, change

```
{this.hasChildren ? (
              <ul className="panel-body">
                  {this.children}
              </ul>
            ) : (
              ' '
)}
```

to

```
{this.hasChildren ? (
          <ul className="panel-body">
              {this.state.children}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          ' '
)}
```

and there is no need to define `this.children = this.state.children`.

I hope it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you alireza for your help.

I managed to fix it. The problem was that the `<Option />` was receiving too much info. I removed all state calls and left only the if statements like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.hasChildren = this.props.children ? true : false;
      this.hasThumb = this.props.images ? true : false;
      //this.state = this.props;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li className={this.hasChildren ? 'list-group-item':'col-sm-4 list-group-item' }>
          <a className="media">
            {this.hasThumb ? (
            <div className="media-left media-middle">
              <img src={this.props.images.thumbnail} alt={this.props.label} />
            </div>
            ) : (
              ' '
            )}
            <div className="media-body">
              <h4 className="option-name">{this.props.label}</h4>
              <p className="info">{this.props.description}</p>
              <span className="text-success pricing">{this.props.price}</span>
            </div>
          </a>
          {this.hasChildren ? (
              <ul className="panel-body">
                  {this.props.children}
              </ul>
            ) : (
              ' '
            )}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Then modified my stateful component `<StyleOptions />` like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Option from './Option';
import OptionsStore from '../../stores/OptionsStore';

class StyleOptions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      options: OptionsStore.getAllItems(),
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    OptionsStore.on("change", () => {
      this.setState({
        options: OptionsStore.getAllItems(),
      });
      console.log('optionsStore received an update');
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    const allOptions = options.map((option) => {
        const { children } = option;
        const optionChildren = children.map((child) => {
          return <Option {...child} />;
        })
        return <Option {...option} children={optionChildren} />;
    });
    return(
      <div className="col-xs-12">
        <ul className="list-group">
          {allOptions}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StyleOptions;
```

Not sure why it is working correctly now. I suspect that It might have changed because I modified the maps a little bit.

*Old one / Broken one*:

```
const Options = this.state.options.map((parent) => {
        const children = parent.children.map((child) => {
          return (
            <Option {...child} />
          )
        });
        return <Option {...parent} children={children} />;
});
```

**New one/working**:

```
    const { options } = this.state;
    const allOptions = options.map((option) => {
        const { children } = option;
        const optionChildren = children.map((child) => {
          return <Option {...child} />;
        })
        return <Option {...option} children={optionChildren} />;
    });
```